# Flex - ExternalInterface.Call() always returns 'Undefined'

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am trying to get the value of a global variable from JS. The variable is defined in the HEAD section of my HTML document.

```
if(ExternalInterface.available){                    
                return ExternalInterface.call("window.myVar.toString()");
            }
```

As I debug my application this call keeps returning "undefined" but if I make the same call in firebug's console it returns a string as expected. I'm very new to flex so is there something I am missing here?

Comment: `ExternalInterface.call` is used to call a js function not getting variables

Comment: I'm having the same problem.  It's returning undefined no matter what I do.  My flash object has an id assigned by swfobject, confirmed by inspecting the element in chrome.  The return value is untyped and when I try to check its type or display it in AS3, it is undefined.

Answer (score 3):

Just try `window.myVar.toString` , you don't need the parenthesis.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was ME. When debugging the tool is not being hosted on a webserver, therefore, the JS is not going to work. Duh..

Answer (score 0):

am sure this url will be very helpful to you http://circlecube.com/2008/02/actionscript-javascript-communication/

you need to convert it into as3 because it's in as2

found this in as3 : http://meshfields.de/externalinterface-call-as3-javascript/